# F# check if 2 maps are identical

Tags: f#

Is there any short way to check if 2 maps are identical?

For example

```
map [("a", 10)]
map [("a", 10)]
```

-> identical

```
map [("b", 10)]
map [("b", 11)]
```

-> not identical

Comment: Not sure I understand the close vote on this.  Granted it's not the best question in the history of Stack Overflow, I'm not sure why anyone would think it should be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `=` appears to work

```
>   Map.ofArray [| (1,"A");(2,"B") |] =   Map.ofArray [| (1,"A");(2,"B") |];;
val it : bool = true
>   Map.ofArray [| (1,"A");(2,"B") |] =   Map.ofArray [| (1,"A");(3,"B") |];;
val it : bool = false
```

Comment: Because map support structural comparison I suppose. That's one more area where F# saves much time.

Answer (score 1):

F# uses structural comparison in most cases and there in particular your comparision would be true.